# DeviceUniqueId & Azure Mobile Service

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, azure-mobile-services

**Problem**

I have Windows Phone 8 app. From the app users can upload photos, then add entry to the table for processing using Azure Mobile Service. One of the columns in a table is DeviceId.
This part works fine.

In another view folks could load list of entries they already have added. Unfortunately for some users this doesnt seem to work as it returns no entries (I can find their entries in database).

Please help as I cant figure out why it works for some users and not others.

**Here is how I get DeviceUniqueId:**

```
byte[] myDeviceID = (byte[])Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("DeviceUniqueId");
string DeviceIDAsString = Convert.ToBase64String(myDeviceID);
```

**Here is how I add new entries:**
TimelapseBatch.DeviceId (first param in  constructor is string)

```
var item = new TimelapseBatch(DeviceInfo.DeviceUniqueId, /*other properties go here*/);
await App.MobileService.GetTable<TimelapseBatch>().InsertAsync(item);
```

**How I query the service**

```
private readonly IMobileServiceTable<TimelapseBatch> batchesTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<TimelapseBatch>();
...
batches = await batchesTable.Where(t => t.DeviceId == DeviceInfo.DeviceUniqueId).ToListAsync();

var processed = batches.Where(t => t.StatusCode == (int)BatchStatus.Processed).OrderByDescending(t => t.Processed).Select(t => new Timelapse()
{
    Page = new Uri(t.PlayerUrl),
    Thumbnail = new Uri(t.ThumbnailUrl)
}).ToList();
```

Apparently after all of this processed doesnt contain any entries even though according to the database it should.

I did verify that when the same users (even those that experience issues) create multiple entries, DeviceId in the database seems to be the same.

Please help, why could it work for some users but not others???

**UPDATE**

So when I use DeviceUniqueId from customers who experience issues I can reproduce the problem.

Also, if I do it this way:

```
batches = await batchesTable.Take(200).ToListAsync();
batches = batches.Where(t => t.DeviceId == DeviceInfo.DeviceUniqueId).ToList();
```

It populates batches as expected. However if I do this (below), batches are empty (I specified 200 for testing purposes as there are fewer entries).

```
batches = await batchesTable.Take(200).Where(t => t.DeviceId == DeviceInfo.DeviceUniqueId).ToListAsync();
```

**UPDATE 2**

It seems like comparison fails if DeviceId contains "+" sign. If I do

```
t.DeviceId.Substring(0,X) == DeviceInfo.DeviceUniqueId.Substring(0,X)
```

Where X is position of + sign, then it works as expected. Omg. Now I'm desperately trying to find a workaround.

**UPDATE 3**

Type definition:

```
public enum BatchStatus
{
    QueuedUp = 0,
    Processed = 1,
    Error = 2,
}

public class TimelapseBatch
{
    public TimelapseBatch()
    {
        TimelapseId = String.Empty;
        DeviceId = String.Empty;
        ContainerUrl = String.Empty;
        VideoMp4Url = String.Empty;
        VideoWebmUrl = String.Empty;
        ThumbnailUrl = String.Empty;
        Uploaded = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1);
        Processed = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1);
        PlayerUrl = String.Empty;
    }

    public TimelapseBatch(string deviceId, string timelapseId, string containerUrl, int photosCount, int fps):this()
    {
        DeviceId = deviceId;
        ContainerUrl = containerUrl;
        TimelapseId = timelapseId;
        PhotosCount = photosCount;
        Fps = fps;
        StatusCode = (int) BatchStatus.QueuedUp;
        Uploaded = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }

    public string TimelapseId { get; set; }
    public string DeviceId { get; set; }
    public string ContainerUrl { get; set; }
    public int PhotosCount { get; set; }
    public int Fps { get; set; }
    public DateTime Uploaded { get; set; }


    public string VideoMp4Url { get; set; }
    public string VideoWebmUrl { get; set; }
    public string ThumbnailUrl { get; set; }
    public double VideoSize { get; set; }
    public DateTime Processed { get; set; }

    public string PlayerUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Currently there is a total of 200 rows in the table. With 66 unique device id.

Comment: Can you narrow down where the problem is happening? Do you get zero results on the `batches` variable, or on the `processed` ones?

Comment: Dont know yet, waiting for app update to get approved. Seems like it's on `batches` one.

Comment: Does it work when you run on your local developer box / emulator?

Comment: I've updated my post with recent findings.

Comment: Interesting... what is the type of the `DeviceId` property? Can you post the type definition?

Comment: It's a string. And now I've updated my post one more time.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26988/discussion-between-maxim-and-carlosfigueira)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And now the solution:

```
 batches = await batchesTable.Where(t => t.DeviceId == DeviceInfo.DeviceUniqueId.Replace("+", "%2B") || t.DeviceId == DeviceInfo.DeviceUniqueId).ToListAsync();
```

I had to manually escape + sign as %2B. Added extra condition in case Azure team will fix it the bug.

Comment: Hi Maxim, this bug has been fixed in the version of the SDK which was released some weeks ago and can be downloaded from the Windows Azure website (0.2.5). It existed up to the previous version (0.2.4). If you update your SDK from http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/downloads/, this bug should be fixed.

Comment: Thank you, Carlos. I'll download it tonight.

Comment: Carlos, I dont see v0.2.5. I downloaded azuresdk-win8-v0.2.5.exe from azure site. It installs into C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\ExtensionSDKs\MobileServicesManagedClient\0.2.0.0\References\CommonConfiguration\neutral folder & the only version I have available is 0.2.0 when I go to add new reference. Nuget also shows 0.2.0 only.

Comment: The version on VS is still 0.2.0; you have the correct SDK (azuresdk-win8-v0.2.5.exe). That version (or the version on NuGet) should have the bug fixed.